# Rust mutable String declaration from String reference argument

Tags: rust

I have

```
fn main() {
    let x = String::from("12");
    fun1(&x);
}
fn fun1(in_fun: &String) {
    let mut y = _______;
    y.push_str("z");
    println!("in fun {}", y);
}
```

where `_____` is the code for declaring `y` based on the argument `in_fun`.

At first I tried `let mut y = *in_fun;` which errors `move occurs because '*in_fun' has type 'String', which does not implement the 'Copy' trait` and also `let mut y = String::from(*in_fun);` which gives same error.

The thing that worked was `let mut y = String::from(format!("{}", *in_fun));`.

1. Is this the right way to declare a mutable `String` from `&String`?
2. Also I still don't understand why dereferencing `&String` with `*` errors? I understood `*&` dereferencing to returns just the value of the reference.

Comment: You have to [clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/clone.html) the string. See [*The Rust Programming Language*: Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) for more information.

Comment: `let mut y = in_fun.clone()` works but `let mut y = *in_fun.clone()` doesn't. Isn't that thing I want to clone `String` not `&String` (as was passed in the function).

Comment: `in_fun.clone()` will clone the `String`. The `.clone()` method takes `self` by reference so the `String` implementation matches better than cloning the reference itself.

Comment: @kmdreko But isn't `in_fun` passed as a `&String` rather than `String` into the function? Do methods on the thing being referenced also pass to the reference (e.g. `.clone()`)? Or do you mean modify the signature so it takes `String` instead?

Comment: *"Do methods on the thing being referenced also pass to the reference"* - often, but it does depend on the function signature (whether its `self` or `&self`) and what other options are available. Consider looking at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) that discusses how function-lookup is deduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the working code:

```rust
fn fun1(in_fun: &String) {
    let mut y = in_fun.clone();
    y.push_str("z");
    println!("in fun {}", y);
}
```

Or, your instincts tell you you have to dereference, so `(*in_fun).clone()` works just the same, but is a bit redundant. `*in_fun.clone()` does **NOT** work because it's equivalent to `*(in_fun.clone())` (dereferencing the clone), which isn't what you want. The reason you don't need to dereference the reference before calling `clone` is because [Rust's method resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/5923139) allows you to call methods of a type or access properties of a type using a reference to the type, and `.clone` has an `&self` receiver.

The reason that `let mut y = *in_fun` doesn't work is because this attempts to move the string out from underneath the reference, which doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't realize that `.clone()` occurred before `*`, I thought the precedence was simply left to right.

Answer (score 3):

`&String` is an immutable reference. Rust is strict about this and prevents many common mishaps we people tend to run into. Dereferencing &String is not possible as it would break the guarantees of safety in rust, allowing you to modify where you only have read access. See the [ownership explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html).

The function should either accept a mutable reference `&mut String` (then the string can be modified in place) or it needs to `.clone()` the string from the immutable reference.

Taking a mutable reference is more efficient than cloning, but it restricts the caller from sharing it immutably in parallel.

If the only thing you want to achieve is to print out some additional information, the best way I know of is:

```rust
fn fun1<S: std::fmt::Display>(in_fun: S) {
    println!("in fun {}z", in_fun);
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("12");
    fun1(&x);
    fun1(&mut x);
    fun1(x);
    fun1("12");
}
```

I use a `Display` trait so anything that implements will do. See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=afe9247cfb88d753287348016bdd4826).

On the other hand, if you really need an owned string, then ask for it :)

```rust
fn fun1<S: Into<String>>(in_fun: S) {
    let mut y = in_fun.into();
    y.push('z');
    println!("in fun {}", y);
}

fn main() {
    let x = String::from("12");
    fun1(&x);
    fun1(x);
    fun1("12");
}
```

This way you can accept both &str and String and keep efficient, avoiding cloning if possible.

Comment: Would this `let mut y = in_fun.into();` implicitly clone?

Comment: @C14L, not in case of `String`, for same types it is an identity function https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#552-556 Otherwise it depends on the implementation of Into/From. `&str` has to be cloned.

Comment: Interesting. But, wouldn't mutating `y` change the same data that `in_fun` also points to?

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that the relationship between reference `&` and dereference `*` was like function and inverse function, s.t. f^-1(f(x)) = *&x

Comment: @C14L, it will if it is an owned value, like `String`, but then it is OK because no-one else has access except the current scope, the `String` cannot be accessed any other way (safely). And if the param is `&str`, `.into()` will clone it so it is OK.